# jQuery Drag Div to Scale image?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a PNG that is 185x185, and it is inside of a div. I have another floating div that is invisible and ontop of a control that I want to user to be able to drag and have the entire div size increase.

Any idea of how I could do this? I would just have an image tag inside a div and increase/decrease width/height portorational to the difference in drag, but I don't know how to allow the div to be dragged.

Comment: You mean something like jQuery-ui resizable (http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/)?

Comment: The simplest is to use jQuery UI resizable. You put your image imside the resizable div and set its width 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is to take jQuery-ui resizable.

Initialize it with:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "[class or id of your div]" ).resizable();
  });
```